# Cargar .kv desde with en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Amigos estaba trabajando con mi codigo desde kivy y resulta que estoy cargando el archivo .kv con el siguiente codigo para que me soporte los caracteres especiles asi:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    # inicio de la app
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "Alcoholímetria - Reconocimiento Facial"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Indigo"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def build(self):
        with open("style.kv", encoding='utf-8') as kv_file:
            return Builder.load_string(kv_file.read())
```

pero resulta que me empezo a saltar un error y es el siguiente no se por que me sale este tipo de error he estado revisando la documentacion de kivy pero no veo diferencia espero me puedan ayudar este es el error que me esta presentando:

```
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\001. PyImage_Project\Alcoholimetro\alcoh\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "main.py", line 30, in build
     return Builder.load_string(kv_file.read())
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\001. PyImage_Project\Alcoholimetro\alcoh\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 405, in load_string
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\001. PyImage_Project\Alcoholimetro\alcoh\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     child, crule, rootrule, rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\001. PyImage_Project\Alcoholimetro\alcoh\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 616, in _apply_rule
     cls = Factory_get(cname)
   File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\001. PyImage_Project\Alcoholimetro\alcoh\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 130, in __getattr__     
     raise AttributeError
 AttributeError
```

Gracias amigos por sus ayudas

Comment: hola, si lo vas a cargar de un archivo, por qué no usar `Builder.load_file("style.kv")` ? Solo sugiero! Pero bueno, en cuanto a la pregunta, porfa incluye el archivo `.kv`, porque puede que el problema esté ahí

Comment: Si me tocó realizarlos de esta manera, ya que cómo lo tenía me leía los caracteres especiales gracias amigos por sus ayudas

Comment: debe ser por el encoding, probablemente estabas usando uno de windows, no utf-8... Entonces solo hacer eso te sirviò?

Comment: Si Funciono pues no me funciono los signos de especiales pero necesitaba prersentarlo y funciono como lo estaba realizando despues buscare la forma de solucionar esos erres de los caracteres especiales gracias amigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de usar

```
with open("style.kv", encoding='utf-8') as kv_file:
    return Builder.load_string(kv_file.read())
```

Se usa

```
Builder.load_file("style.kv")
```

Porque algunos caracteres especiales no se estaban leyendo correctamente